# AppleScript - Paste a file in every folder and sub folder of directory

Tags: applescript

I have a directory with sub directories. I want to put a file in every folder, without the use of sudo commands. I only want to use apple script code and terminal commands, using the command line:

```
do shell script ""
```

The file is called hello.png

I'd love any help! :) Thank you all!

Comment: One thing you might consider, if the file is always the same, is making a link to the file from each folder, rather than putting a whole copy of the file in each folder. This might have a couple of benefits - it will take less space if the file `hello.png` is big and secondly, if you want to change the file in all directories, you just change the one that they all link to and they will change throughout. Just a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy is now done in all sub folders of the main folder (what ever the recursive level is.

The script bellow does what you want :

```
set MyFile to choose file with prompt "Select file to be duplicated in every folder"
set MyFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder in which you want to copy the file"

tell application "Finder"
set SubFolders to every folder of entire contents of MyFolder
repeat with aFolder in SubFolders
    duplicate MyFile to aFolder
end repeat
end tell
```

I made assumption that you want to duplicate the selected file to all sub-folders of the selected folder. Then, I did not add recursive search for sub-folders of sub-folders of ...

In this script, I just used Applescript commands. You can replace the "duplicate" line with a do shell script command (using shell command 'cp'). However in this case the script must use posix path and quoted form...which is more complex than the simple Finder duplicate instruction !

Comment: This is just what I wanted! However, I was just wondering if you could make it do the recursive search for all sub-folders of sub-folders please? I sat and tried this too, but I can't figure out how. Thank you very much pbell!

Comment: I have updated my first script to add the recursivity. The copy will now be done in every sub folder of the selected folder, what ever the level is.